# New Installation on Windows 10 IIS, cannot get to admin control panel, getting "Template not found: unavailable"

Tags: installation, 404, windows

I am in process of doing a new installation of CraftCMS, and I have the site up and configured. When I select the "Go to your control panel" link I am getting a Craft 404 error: "HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
Template not found: unavailable", trying to take me too "https:///admin". When I manually enter: "https:///index.php?p=admin/login", I can get to the admin login page.

[image: login]

When I log in from there it goes back to the same 404 error. I am thinking it could be the rewrite rule is not working properly because at the bottom of the error page I do see "p=unavailable".

[image: parameters]

I have tested the rewrite rule in IIS and it does not seem correct to me:

[image: rewrite]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been fighting with this installation for a couple of days now and late nights it seems I am getting close and I think if I could get around this last issues I will be good, but I thought that with the last one.

Amazingly enough, after I logged in and went to the 404 page, I was able to manually type in: https:///index.php?p=admin/dashboard and was able to see the dashboard, but as soon as you click on anything it goes back to the 404.

Comment: What's the part that's been redacted? `localhost` or an actual dev domain? i.e. `mytestsite.test`?